# Language cross platform that allows different socks connection per thread

Tags: java, c#, cross-platform, sockets

Hello i'm developing an app that needs to do many requests with different socks connections. I was doing it in C# but i'm not sure how well it will work on a linux server even with .net core .

Java Socks connection is unique for the JVM correct?

It needs to have 100+ different socks connection and can't be that thread heavy , so it will need to change on the go in the same thread.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by "different socks connections" -- are you talking about a SOCKS proxy server?  If so, which version?

Comment: Also, by "different connections" do you  mean using different servers?  Because otherwise you just get a new connection every time you try to connect to a remote server.  But using multiple proxy servers at the same time is a little bit of an unusual requirement...

Comment: Yes is using multiple proxy servers at same time.

Answer (score 0):

The most common way to use a SOCKS proxy server in the Linux world is to do so via a shared library that intercepts calls to standard socket functions and redirects them to the proxy server.  This does not allow multiple connections to different servers, however (except by configuring different servers for different addresses, but that doesn't seem to be what you're trying to do).

In order to connect to multiple servers, you will need to use a direct SOCKS client implementation, rather than relying on your underlying sockets library.  For example, [this library running under Java](https://github.com/fengyouchao/sockslib) should be able to do what you want, as long as your servers are SOCKS5 capable.